# List parameters to a function from binary executable

Tags: x86, analysis, disassembly

I'm looking to do analysis on the binary executable of a program to create a list of parameters to a specific function call. I can use OllyDbg to find a list of all calls to the function, but don't see anything to show the parameters without actually executing the code.

It looks like the function takes 2 parameters, each supplied with a simple PUSH directly before the CALL in each instance. I can use DiStorm to pore over the code for this single instance, but I'd prefer a more general solution that I can use elsewhere. OllyDbg does seem to know the number of parameters when stepping into the function, so I'd think it's possible to determine the number of parameters through static analysis, but my understanding of x86 assembly is honestly very limited.

Is there an existing way to do this, or is my only option to use DiStorm and just grab the last 2 PUSH statements before each CALL to this function?

Comment: There's no requirement that the arguments to a function be placed on the stack with a PUSH instruction.  And of course on ABIs other than standard i386 C functions the arguments may be passed in registers.  In fact it can be impossible in some cases even to tell how many arguments were passed.  There is no way to do this in the general case; your best bet is to trap the calls and log the arguments at runtime.

Comment: Is the case where it is impossible to tell how many functions were passed in limited to variable-argument functions? If so, I don't anticipate running into any of those.

I'm aware that function arguments don't NEED to be via PUSH or even in the stack at all. I need a solution for this specific case (where the arguments are on the stack and put there by PUSH), but would prefer a more general solution, if one exists. It doesn't need to account for every single possible method of passing arguments.

Comment: It's difficult to define general solution for getting parameters in a bytecode that doesn't have fixed method/function definitions (as Java or .NET have). You can try to turn off every optimalisation and that might cause solely pushing parameters on stack. But optimalisation is optimalisation and these things differ from processor to processor. For example ARM has registers (IIRC `r2` through `r5`) for parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think of doing this is by going through the function and checking all the references to `EBP`.

In a function prolog, you will typically see:

```
push ebp
mov  ebp, esp
sub  esp,n
```

This is where the new function stack frame is being set up. Which will look a bit like this

```
EBP+n -> arg n
         ...
EBP+8 -> arg 0
         return address
EBP   -> stack address
EBP-4 -> local var 0
         ...
EBP-n -> local var n
ESP   ->
```

You can get the number of arguments by examining all the references to `EBP + (n>=8)` within a given function.

Now, you could examine the number of push instructions preceding the function call but there is no guarantee that the function would not reference other parts of the stack.

[IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml) does a pretty good job of calculating function arguments. I suggest you give that a go! You'll see something like this:

```
.text:00022042                   ; int __stdcall sub_22042(USHORT, char, char)
.text:00022042                   sub_22042 proc near     ; CODE XREF: sub_21DC4+73p
.text:00022042                                           ; sub_22524+37p
.text:00022042
.text:00022042                   arg_0= word ptr  8
.text:00022042                   arg_4= byte ptr  0Ch
.text:00022042                   arg_8= byte ptr  10h
.text:00022042
.text:00022042 8B FF                mov     edi, edi
.text:00022044 55                   push    ebp
...
```